# How to write TypeScript types for Axios.get when using 3rd-party API

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js

First question asked here so I will try to summarize everything as good as possible.
I'm trying to define the type of data I get back from an axios.get from the TMDB-API, which is a movie database.

This is how the JSON is structured in my get-request I get back. **(Simplified)**

```
{
    data: {
        results: [
            {
                name: 'Free Guy'
                poster_path: "/yc2IfL701hGkNHRgzmF4C6VKO14.jpg"
            },
            {
                name: 'Squid Game'
                poster_path: "/uu4TgyyW259aOZHN0Ew4TEfjnUG.jpg"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm setting the state like this

```
interface MovieType {
    name: string
    poster_path: string
}

const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[] | []>([]);
```

I'm making my get-request, which gives me the correct JSON specified above.
But I must be doing it wrong since the error I get from TypeScript here is:
`Property 'results' does not exist on type 'DataMovieType'.ts(2339)`

```
interface DataMovieType {
    data: {
        results: MovieType[]
    }
}

const request = await axiosInstance.get<DataMovieType>(fetchUrl);
setMovies(request.data.results);
```

I can circumvent this by not specifying the  `axios.get<Type>`
But then it will be any which I don't want, unless that's the only way to go about it.

I have tried writing the DataMovieType like this as well, but that doesn't work either, since it gives me the same error.

```
interface DataMovieType {
    data: {
        results: {
            name: string
            poster_path: string
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to TypeScript and this might be a simple fix but I'm completely lost now trying to fix this particular problem.

If more info is needed I will happily provide that for you.

Thanks in advance,
Johan.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `request.data.data.results` instead? (although I'll name `request` as `response`)

Comment: This got rid of my error, but it didn't work setting it since then it was an empty object.

Is my DataMovieType wrong then maybe? Should I remove the data and write results directly?

This actually worked but it doesn't make sense to me, how come the data-part of the object just (disappears)?

Comment: Yeah try that, seeing the official documentation it appears that there is no `data` field in JSON. The type/interface (`T`) you have to provide to `axios.get<T>` is reflected in `response.data` (in other words, type of `response.data` is `T` not that of `response`).

Comment: Huge thanks for this, it worked now!


Although it still seems a bit weird to me since this is how it looks when I log the response.


https://imgur.com/a/dyQSwMG


But I guess it is how you described, it defaults to response.data since the config-object is from axios as well. This is what threw me off thinking it was a part of the actual object.

Thank you!

Comment: Some pro tips: Just use some tool like Postman or Insomnia to check the API outputs first (you won't see `data`/`config` there, you will see what the server has actually sent you). Secondly, don't bother much to manually type the response. If the response is in JSON, then there are many online tools (e.g. https://transform.tools) that will create type definitions from the response for you. Also, see this: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L146. It returns `Promise<R>`, and the default `R` is `AxiosResponse<T>`. So `await axios.get<T>()` will give you `AxiosResponse<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this will help a lot when expanding that typeDef for the response.
Yes, I do use postman usually, but was following a video and logged the response and followed along since they didn't use typescript.

Is AxiosResponse<T> wrong then, or how should I go about it?
Should I skip setting the type there and keep it as ```axios.get()``` ?

Comment: No, what you are doing is absolutely fine. `await axios.get<T>()` is absolutely fine. Sorry for the confusion. I just wrote that to tell you its result is not same as what the server has send you. It is `response.data` that the server has send you, and its type should be provided to `axios.get`.

Comment: @JohanEriksson Please add the solution as an answer to your own question. This clearly indicates it already has an answer.

Comment: @juliomalves
I have already done so, did it asap, or should I do it in some other maybe?

Comment: You've added the solution in the question. Instead, add it as an answer to the question below (see 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the answer has now been provided as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from **@brc-dd**

> Seeing the official documentation it appears that there is no data
> field in JSON. The type/interface (T) you have to provide to axios.get
> is reflected in response.data (in other words, type of response.data
> is T not that of response).

What I did wrong was including data in my type which now looks like this, which worked for me.

```
interface DataMovieType {
    results: MovieType[]
}
```